# 2 ways of accessing value of an array of pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, printf, format-specifiers

The first block

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int MAX = 3;

int main() {

    int  var[] = { 10, 100, 200 };
    int i, *ptr[MAX];

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        ptr[i] = &var[i]; /* assign the address of integer. */
    }

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        printf("Value of var[%d] = %d\n", i, *ptr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Easy to understand, since ptr is an array of int pointers. So when you need to access the `i`-th element, you need to dereference its value as `*ptr[i]`.

Now the second block, just the same, but now it points to an array of `char` pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int MAX = 4;

int main() {

    char *names[] = {
        "Zara Ali",
        "Hina Ali",
        "Nuha Ali",
        "Sara Ali",
    };

    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        printf("Value of names[%d] = %s\n", i, names[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This time, when we need to access its element, why don't we add a `*` first?

I tried to form a correct statement to print this value, seems if you dereference, it will be a single char. Why?

```
printf("%c", *names[1]) // Z
```

I know there is no strings in C, and it is a `char` array. And I know pointers, but still don't under the syntax here.

Comment: Because the element that we need to access is an address. The `%s` tells `printf` to print all the characters starting at the given address, and until encountering 0. In your example, the given address is the value of `names[i]`. The `%c` tells `printf` to print the given character.In your example, the given character is the value of `*names[i]`, which is equivalent to `names[i][0]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `printf()` with `%s` format specifier, quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1

> `s`
>  If no `l` length modifier is present, the argument shall be a pointer to the initial
>   element of an array of character type. [...]

In your case,

```
 printf("Value of names[%d] = %s\n", i, names[i] );
```

`names[i]` **is** the pointer, as required by `%s`. That is why, you don't dereference the pointer.

FWIW,

- `%c` expects an `int` type argument (converted to an
  unsigned char,), so you need to dereference the pointer to get the value.
- `%d` also expects an `int` argument, so you have to go ahead and dereference the pointer, as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The `%d` conversion specifier expects its corresponding argument to have type `int`; `ptr[i]` has type `int *`, so the dereference is necessary.

The `%s` conversion specifier expects its corresponding argument to have type `char *`; that is, a *pointer* to `char`.  So `names[i]` is already of the correct type.  The `%s` specifier tells `printf` to print the *sequence* of characters starting at the given location until it sees the string terminator.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the same syntax in the second example if you were printing the first character of each array of `char`:

```
    printf("Value of names[%d] = %c\n", i, *names[i]);
```

But since you want to print the C strings, you pass the values of the elements of the `names` array, which are of the proper type, `char *`.

Answer (score 0):

`printf()` has it's own way of dealing with format type specifiers. In case of strings, that is, array of characters, it requires the `%s` specifier and a pointer of type `char *` as a corresponding argument. When `printf()` receives this pointer, it dereference it discreetly to print the characters that are of type `char`. So, that is why you pass a pointer and don't dereference when you want to print strings.